# Assembling Multi Dimensional JSON object

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to assemble this JSON object of [Baobab](http://www.sideralis.org/baobab/index.html) data (tree structure).  I have the following recursive function:

```
/* Takes the Tree (in this case, always '1') and the Parent ID where we want to start, this case, I would also start with '1' */
function walkTree($tree, $id)
{
     /* Gets the children of that of that ID */
     $children = $tree->getChildren($id);

     $data = "";

     /* Loop through the Children */
     foreach($children as $index => $value) 
     {
          /* A function to get the 'Name' associated with that ID */
          $name = getNodeName($tree, $value);

          /* Call the walkTree() function again, this time based on that Child ID */
          $ret = walkTree($tree, $value);

          /* Append the string to $data */
          $data .= '{"data":"'.$name.'","attr": {"id" : "'.$value.'"}
                   ,"state":"closed","children": ['.$ret.']}';
     }

     /* Return the final result */
     return $data;
}
```

This is very close to working but as you see, there are no commas between each nested object and array, so the JSON is improperly formatted.  Lots of the following:

...   {`"data":"Personal","attr": {"id" : "4"},"state":"closed","children": []}{"data":"News-editorial","attr": {"id" : "5"},"state":"closed","children": []`...

I believe the best way would be to create a Php array and `json_encode()` it, but I can't find a way to make the nested Objects work.

Comment: Can i ask why you are doing this instead of `json_encode`

Comment: well like I said in the question, I can't figure out the proper function to assemble the Php array.  This is the closest I've gotten so far.  But yes, I agree that a Php array, and josn_encode() makes the most sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you wanted to build this out through concatenation then just keep track of the first and subsequent elements.  This modified code should work:

```
/* Takes the Tree (in this case, always '1') and the Parent ID where we want to start, this case, I would also start with '1' */
function walkTree($tree, $id)
{
  /* Gets the children of that of that ID */
  $children = $tree->getChildren($id);
  $first = true;

  $data = "";

  /* Loop through the Children */
  foreach($children as $index => $value) 
  {
    /* A function to get the 'Name' associated with that ID */
    $name = getNodeName($tree, $value);

    /* Call the walkTree() function again, this time based on that Child ID */
    $ret = walkTree($tree, $value);

    /* Append the string to $data */
    if($first) {
       $first = false;
    } else {
      /*add comma for each element after the first*/
      $data .= ',';
    }
    $data .= '{"data":"'.$name.'","attr": {"id" : "'.$value.'"},"state":"closed","children": ['.$ret.']}';
  }

  /* Return the final result */
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have soothing like this instead

```
$data = array();

foreach($children as $index => $value)
{
    $node = array();
    $node['data'] = getNodeName($tree, $value) ;
    $node['attr'] = array("id"=>$value,"state"=>"closed","children"=>walkTree($tree, $value)) ;

    $data[] = $node ;
}

return json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This is a much smarter solution than mine

Comment: @Jason Sperske am sure you can improve on it to achieve what you want ... let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be working.  The 'children' key is not being populated, it's just blank for each.  And the there's only 1 level to the array

Comment: @dtj working with limited data .. have no idea what `$tree` looks like